# Checking a position's bounds before accessing it

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a out 2D array and determine the element North, South, East, and West of the starting element. I have filled the array with random ints but need help with printing a "-1" for that direction if the direction is out of bounds instead of making the entire program crash

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetNeighbors
{

    public static void printRow(int[]row) 
        {
            for (int i : row) {
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number of rows");
        int r=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a number of columns");
        int c=kb.nextInt();

        int[][]spot=new int[r][c];

        arrayWork(spot);
        directionWork(spot);

    }

    public static void arrayWork(int[][]spot)
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<spot.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<spot[i].length;j++)
            {
                spot[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*1001);
            }
        }
        for(int[]row:spot) 
            {
            printRow(row);
            }
    }

    public static void directionWork(int[][]spot)
    {
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please choose a row for an element");
        int row=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please choose a column for an element");
        int col=kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Requested neighbors for element at row "+row+", col "+col+" "+"("+spot[row][col]+")");

        System.out.print("North: "+spot[row-1][col]);
        System.out.print(" South: "+spot[row+1][col]);
        System.out.print(" East: "+spot[row][col+1]);
        System.out.print(" West: "+spot[row][col-1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repeating a bunch of conditionals, you can make a single method that checks if a row and col are in bounds when retrieving a value:

```
public static int getElement(int[][] spot, int row, int col) {
    if (row < spot.length && spot.length > 0 && row >= 0 && col < spot[row].length && spot[row].length > 0 && col >= 0) {
        return spot[row][col];
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then change your print statements to call it:

```
System.out.println("Requested neighbors for element at row "+row+", col "+col+" "+"("+getElement(spot, row, col)+")");

System.out.print("North: "+ getElement(spot, row - 1, col));
System.out.print(" South: " + getElement(spot, row + 1, col));
System.out.print(" East: " + getElement(spot, row, col + 1));
System.out.print(" West: "+ getElement(spot, row, col - 1));
```

Comment: Two more conditions have to be included. `If  [row+1] >= spot.length`... also for column.

Comment: @zlakad No, you only need to check the index being accessed.

Comment: `System.out.println("Requested neighbors for element at row "+row+", col "+col+" "+"("+spot[row][col]+")");` needs to be checked also.

Comment: @user27149 Thanks, added.

Comment: East: `getElement(spot, row, col + 1)`. What if `col` is the most left column? (This is an example).

Comment: @zlakad I still don't understand what you're trying to convey. The conditions I have will ensure that `row` and `col` are in bounds.

Comment: If I understood the question properly, the goal isn't to get an element of 2D array. OP wants to get neighbors  of [row][column]... Also, I might be wrong...

Comment: @zlakad He wants to get the neighbors **while ensuring they are in bounds**. Each print statement calls the `getElement` method with the appropriate `row` and `col` arguments for each different neighbor.

Comment: I am trying to print what element is N S E and W and if for example you pick your starting location to be spot[0][0] your N and W will both be -1 because they are out of bounds

Comment: Well, it seems to me that I didn't read the code at all. Sorry, friend, my intentions were not negative in any way :) Here, in Serbia is 4:21 AM... Huh.

Comment: @Ahawk The code I've provided should accomplish that.

Comment: For some reason I keep being shown the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
error

Comment: @Ahawk Which line is that being thrown from?

Comment: 38, 69, 78. I may have forgotten to call the new method in main

Comment: @Ahawk Yeah `getElement` checks if `row` and `col` are `>= 0` so that can't be thrown by it.

Comment: Okay I think I know what to fix now. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobWood Whenever I input 0's for the int row and int col part of the directionWork method I get the out of bounds error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ahawk Thrown by what line? (Not the number, copy/paste the line please)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at Ideone.getElement(Main.java:77)
 at Ideone.directionWork(Main.java:68)
 at Ideone.main(Main.java:37)

Comment: Found it. The getElement method had the wrong integer names; they had row and col instead of r and c. Thanks